# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello Guys i'm working on a Flutter project whenever i'm running it i get this Error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @35f362dc

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please help guys my Java version is 8 , SDK 20